# How to fix a "SQLiteConnection for gms database" that was leaked

Tags: android, memory-leaks, google-play-services

My application, which uses **Google Play Services**, received the following warning in the logcat

```
 12-06 12:53:58.240 2748-2757/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
    12-06 12:53:58.240 2748-2757/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
    12-06 12:53:58.240 2748-2757/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

...but unlike all the other cases discussed on SO, **my application does not use any databases**,

rather, it seems to be a leak from a database of **Google Play Services**.

How would one fix that?

Answer (score 35):

In Android Studio on **Android Monitor** right corner change from **"Firebase"** to **"Show only selected application"**

Comment: Isn't that like "sticking one's head in the sand"? The warning still exists!

Comment: You saved my Day..!! :) @Minis

Comment: Thanks for the Info... That Helps.. a lot.. I think Its problem with my app or android Studio

Comment: @JoMo I send ticket to Google about that issue can't do more. It's their firebase throwing leak

Comment: that helps me lot

Comment: This is not a solution, this just hides the message.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you clear data from google play store, it would be fine!

Settings->Apps->Google Play Services->MANAGE SPACE->CLEAR ALL DATA

Comment: After  entering "Settings" I don't see "Apps" , and if I put "Apps" into Search I get "Plugin" s with "Google Services" but not "Google Play Services" and not "Manage Space" or "Clear all data". Please advise :)

Comment: This is for android 6.
Which version is yours??

Comment: My mistake, I thought you meant Settings in Android Studio, while you meant on the device.Thanks.

Comment: Your advice did not change anything, see my answer, Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using **Run 'app'** where I kept on getting those warning messages,

I used **Debug 'app'**, whereupon I was informed that I had the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

This made sense because my activity extended **AppCompatActivity**

and in the **Manifest** I had designated  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`

which is evidently not a descendant of **Theme.AppCompat**.

I saw the advice to extend my activity to good old **Activity**, and it worked!

In fact, a short time later the original warning messages recurred and my app stopped working, so I haven't answered the original question :(

Answer (score -1):

this error is just because you do not declare any default constructor in your data class which is accessed by firebase database just create a blank default constructor and it will be fine!